# Troubleshooting Character Encoding Issues in Google Analytics Reports on Android Devices

Tags: android, analytics

I noticed that when I view my website using an Android phone, although the web page displays correctly in the browser with the proper encoding, the titles appear as garbled characters when I access the GA (Google Analytics) reports.

This issue occurs on most Android phones, but not all, and the specific versions vary. What could be causing this, and how can I address it?

ps. my front-end framework is Nuxt.js

my install code:

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'zh-Hant-TW'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
    ]
    ...
  },
  script: [
      {
        src: 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXX',
        type: 'text/javascript',
        async: true
      },
      {
        src: '/js/analytics.js'
      },
    ]
}
```

analtyics:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments)
}
gtag('js', new Date())

gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxx')
```

[image]

[image]